# WMI MOF File with Two Registry KeyPaths

Tags: wmi

Querying Win32_Products can take a very long time, and when trying to query a lot of computers, this has gotten me frustrated. I have never worked with MOF files before, but someone suggested "creating" a new namespace with just the information I am looking for from the registry.

I was pointed to the following MOF code:

```
    #PRAGMA AUTORECOVER

    qualifier dynamic:ToInstance;
    qualifier ProviderClsid:ToInstance;
    qualifier ClassContext:ToInstance;
    qualifier propertycontext:ToInstance; 

    [dynamic, provider("RegProv"),
        ProviderClsid("{fe9af5c0-d3b6-11ce-a5b6-00aa00680c3f}"),
        ClassContext
        ("local|HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall")
    ] 
    class Software {
        [key] string KeyName;
        [read, propertycontext("Publisher")] string Vendor;
        [read, propertycontext("DisplayName")] string ProductName;
        [read, propertycontext("DisplayVersion")] string Version;
        [read, propertycontext("InstallDate")] string InstallDate;
        [read, propertycontext("InstallLocation")] string InstallLocation;
        [read, propertycontext("InstallSource")] string InstallSource;
        [read, propertycontext("UninstallString")] string UninstallString;
    };
```

This works fantastic, but how can I have this check both the Software and Software\Wow6432Node paths? I have tried playing around with it on a VM, but no luck just stabbing in the dark.

I tried:

```
    ("local|HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall")
    ("local|HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall")
```

or

```
    ("local|HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall",
    "local|HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall")
```

And a few other random ideas. Nothing seems to work. How would you approach gathering the info from both registry paths?

I would appreciate any help! This would knock minutes off my scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either create two separate `MOF` files (one for each registry path), or use multiple instantiated `__Win32Provider`, something as follows

```
#PRAGMA AUTORECOVER
#pragma namespace("\\\\.\\root\\CimV2")

qualifier dynamic:ToInstance;
qualifier ProviderClsid:ToInstance;
qualifier ClassContext:ToInstance;
qualifier propertycontext:ToInstance; 

Instance of __Win32Provider as $prov32bit
{
  Name = "RegProv32";
  // ClsId = "{fe9af5c0-d3b6-11ce-a5b6-00aa00680c3f}";
};

Instance of __Win32Provider as $prov64bit
{
  Name = "RegProv64";
  // ClsId = "{fe9af5c0-d3b6-11ce-a5b6-00aa00680c3f}";
};

[dynamic, provider($prov32bit),
    ProviderClsid("{fe9af5c0-d3b6-11ce-a5b6-00aa00680c3f}"),
    ClassContext
    ("local|HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall")
] 

[dynamic, provider($prov64bit),
    ProviderClsid("{fe9af5c0-d3b6-11ce-a5b6-00aa00680c3f}"),
    ClassContext
    ("local|HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall")
]
```

Pretty sure about necessity to double the `class Software` part as well. Not sure about all `ToInstance` [qualifier flavors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa392900(v=vs.85).aspx) rightness. And last not least, above script does not care for the `Wow6432Node` existence. However, [this solution looks good](http://poshcode.org/2470):

> This script creates a `WMI` Class `Win32_AddRemovePrograms` (and, on 64bit
>   systems, a `Win32_AddRemovePrograms32` for 32bit apps) which are backed
>   by the registry provider.  They can then be queried to list installed
>   apps (and versions) and perform much faster than running the same
>   queries using the PowerShell Registry provider. Additionally, they can
>   be used in GPO policies, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I did in fact just create two separate MOF files. It would have been nice to have a collection of both 32 and 64-bit software in one namespace, but individually works as well.

Comment: On: "Not sure about all ToInstance qualifier flavors rightness.": The DMTF specs had ToInstance in the CIM-XML specs, where it got deprecated in DSP0201 2.4, but it never was described in DSP0004. So at this point, ToInstance is a Microsoft-specific flavor (like Amended, NotToInstance, and 
NotToSubClass).